# Does set_target_properties in CMake override CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

At the beginning of my CMake project, I'm setting general compilation flags in the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, like

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-W -Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Later on, I need to append additional configuration-specific compilation flags (stored in BUILD_FLAGS). Can I use the following command for this:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${BUILD_FLAGS})
```

or do I have to add the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS manually:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${BUILD_FLAGS}")
```

to prevent CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS being overriden by BUILD_FLAGS?

Comment: I believe that they are appended to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, you can verify this by invoking a verbose make file `make target VERBOSE=1`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the first one:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${BUILD_FLAGS})
```

The flags stored in BUILD_FLAGS are appended after CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS when compiling the sources of TARGET. The documentation hints at this, but I've just tried it to make sure.

> COMPILE_FLAGS
>
> ```
>    Additional flags to use when compiling this target's sources. 
>    
>    The COMPILE_FLAGS property sets additional compiler flags used to
>    build sources within the target.  Use COMPILE_DEFINITIONS to
>    pass additional preprocessor definitions.
> ```

The full command line will be the equivalent of:

```
${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${COMPILE_FLAGS} -o foo.o -c foo.cc
```

And as Ramon said, you can always check with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much (and to Ramon too). I also didn't know about the VERBOSE parameter before and it is now much easier for me to learn how CMake actually processes my commands.

Answer (score 72):

<sup>The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101557/938111) is still working but outdated since 2013. 

This answer is based and new functions from CMake v2.8.12, v3.3 and v3.13.</sup>

### Since CMake-2.8.12 (2013)

Two new commands to set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

- [`target_compile_options()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_compile_options) (for one single target)
- [`add_compile_options()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_compile_options) (for all targets)

The documentation of last version has not changed a lot since **cmake-2.8.12**:

- [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html)
- [`add_compile_options()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html)

In you case you can use:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE ${BUILD_FLAGS})
```

Or simply if you have a single target:

```
add_compile_options(${BUILD_FLAGS})
```

### More examples

```
target_compile_options(mylib PRIVATE   -O2) # only internal
target_compile_options(mylib INTERFACE -gl) # only external
target_compile_options(mylib PUBLIC    -g)  # same as PRIVATE + INTERFACE

# multiple targets and flags
target_compile_options(mylib1 mylib2 PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)

target_compile_options(    mylib PUBLIC -DUSEXX)  # Bad
target_compile_definitions(mylib PUBLIC -DUSEXX)  # OK

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra) # for all targets in current directory
add_compile_options(-DUSEXX)       # Bad
add_definitions(-DUSEXX)           # OK
```

### Deprecated `COMPILE_FLAGS`

[**cmake-3.0** documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/COMPILE_FLAGS.html) flags `COMPILE_FLAGS` as deprecated:

> `COMPILE_FLAGS`
>
> Additional flags to use when compiling this target’s sources.
>
> The `COMPILE_FLAGS` property sets additional compiler flags used to
>   build sources within the target. Use `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` to pass
>   additional preprocessor definitions.
>
> This property is deprecated. Use the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property or the
>   `target_compile_options` command instead.

If you still want to use `set_target_properties()` you may use `COMPILE_OPTIONS` instead  of `COMPILE_FLAGS`:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS ${BUILD_FLAGS})
```

### Since CMake-3.3 (2015)

[Anton Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/u/423959) suggests to use [**generator expressions**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) as presented in an [answer of ar31](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21561742/938111).

The CMake **generator expressions** applies your `${BUILD_FLAGS}` to:

- C++ language using `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>` (can also be `C`, `CUDA`...)
- Clang compiler using `$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>`
  (can also be `GNU` for `gcc`, or `MSVC`for Visual C++... see [full list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html))
  (use `$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>` instead if language is C)
- and more as *supported C++ feature* or *compiler version*... (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html))

In you case you can use:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE
          $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_CXX}>
          $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_C}>)
```

or about compilers:

```
target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE
          $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_CLANG}>
          $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_GCC}>
          $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_VISUAL}>)
```

### Since CMake-3.13 (2018)

A new function [`target_link_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_options.html) allow to pass options to the linker, as mentioned by [Craig Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938798/craig-scott).

### Different options for C and C++ files

The best way is to distinguish C files and C++ files using two different targets.

Comment: What if you have mixed target? For example C and C++. How do you set options only for C target?

Comment: Hi @Martin. I do not know about a target mixing C and C++ files using different options each kind of source file. I may suggest to split this target in two : one target for C source code and the other one for C++. ... OK I am starting to add a section in may answer to propose a way to address this complex situation...

Comment: Why can't I use `set_target_properties()` with `LINK_FLAGS` the same way? It seems it never accepts more than one flag (Even in list form).

Comment: Hi @Royi, I do not know because I not use `set_target_properties()`. This function is an old usage of CMake (close to Makefiles mind). Hope you will find a modern way to use CMake. Have fun, Cheers

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't using "Target Properties" the "Modern" way using Cmake?

Comment: Hi @Royi. Sorry, yes, function `set_target_properties()` is still useful nowadays, and I use it sometimes as for `set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)` or `set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE True)`. I mean I prefer to use modern functions [`target_*()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html#id4) when possible. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes. I also prefer those. Yet there is none for the Linker Flags unless I'm missing something. Thank You.

Comment: @olibre Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21561742/423959 for language specific options. The right way is to use generator expressions.

Comment: @Royi "Yet there is none for the Linker Flags unless I'm missing something." --> CMake 3.13 adds the `target_link_options()` command which fills this gap, but you have always been able to (ab)use `target_link_libraries()` to add linker flags.

Comment: `$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_CXX}>` is probably a mistake, it should rather be `$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${BUILD_FLAGS_FOR_C}>`

Comment: Thank you @AdamRomanek  I have fixed the mistake.  \o/   Cheers

Comment: @oHo I couldn't find any docs related to having multiple targets in one option like the one you mentioned in your answer: "target_compile_options(mylib1 mylib2 PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)" do you have any refs? Also, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry @AMCoded since 2019 I have stopped using CMake (I was also a CMake coder). I am currently coding in Go/TS/Python and I have forgotten my CMake knowledge!