# Changing CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in project

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags

I have the following content in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
project( Matfile )

SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x" )

set ( SOURCES
      "foo.cpp"
      "bar.cpp"
    )

add_library(
        Matfile
        ${SOURCES}
)
```

As you may imagine, what I want to do is to compile my C++ sources using the flag -std=c++0x (I'm using gcc and I need the C++11 features). Unfortunately, this does not work, in the sense that, when I use cmake to generate the makefiles, the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is completely void.

How can I set this variable in the project file?

It seems to be a very stupid question, but I just spent not less than two houres trying to figure this out.

Comment: The `set` command for the flags looks well formed (although for gcc v4.7 onwards, the flag should be `-std=c++11` I think).  What do you mean by "completely void"?  What is the output if you run `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: Possibly the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS are set correctly in the Makefile but are shown empty in the `CMakeCache.txt` File. It is therefore insufficient to check in the CMakeCache unless you FORCE it to be written back to the cache (use `set (var value CACHE STRING "" FORCE`)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The most straightforward solution should be using [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) if you are using version 2.8.12 or newer.
For older versions you can "abuse" [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html). While it is only meant for add -D flags, it also works with any other compiler flag. However, I think it is not meant to be used that way and could break in a future version.

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++0x) # CMake 2.8.12 or newer
```

or

```
add_definitions(-std=c++0x) # CMake 2.8.11 or older
```

Starting with CMake 3.3 you can also make this flag only apply to a specific language (e.g. only C or C++) using the strange generator expressions syntax:

```
 add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++14> $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-std=c99>)
```

However this will [not work with the Visual studio generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-expressions), so make sure to only use this for Make/Ninja generators or use [target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) to set it on a per-target scope.

Comment: Good, but in this case it has one problem, these arguments are also added to C_COMPILER not only for CXX and C don't support some args which are for CXX, especially `-std=c++0x`. in this case is better solution `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)`.

Comment: CMake 3.3 and newer has a solution for this now using generator expressions.

Answer (score 30):

The correct way to [set the C++ standard in CMake 3.1 and later](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) is:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)
```

It is possible to [specify the standard for one individual target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD) also:

```
set_property(TARGET mylib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Since CMake 3.8 there is a [new option to the `target_compile_features` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards) that allows to set the required standard for a target:

```
target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

The advantage would be that it propagates the requirement to dependent targets. If you compile a library with the `cxx_std_11` required feature, any binary that links to it will automatically have this requirement set.

Answer (score 14):

Does it help to use the `FORCE` flag?

```
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x" CACHE STRING "compile flags" FORCE)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that made the flags show up in the `ccmake` curses gui, which is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Christopher Bruns Is there any way to do this and leave the docstring alone (i.e. don't specify "compile flags")?

Comment: @DavidDoria Yes, you can reuse the previous docstring, but it's not pretty. https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/SettingVariableGroups

Comment: this SET mean add or replace configuration set in other files?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this would work better:

```
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCES}
       PROPERTIES
       COMPILE_FLAGS  "-std=c++0x")
```

Comment: Thanks, this work. But in case of larger project, with more outputs, like a few libraries and a few executables, assuming that all of them are to be compiled with the same flags, should I repeat this statements many times? There is no command to set the compilation flags for **all** the source files?

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on the ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS() with generator expression answer by ar31, you may run into a problem when you want to add multiple flags separated by spaces, as cmake has a [nasty bug in generator expressions](https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=14353).

The solution I used was a FOREACH loop, here is an example from the project I'm working on:

```
IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
    # common flags
    SET(MY_C_AND_CXX_FLAGS -mtune=generic -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -fomit-frame-pointer -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=4 -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -feliminate-unused-debug-types)

    SET(MY_C_FLAGS   ${MY_C_FLAGS}   ${MY_C_AND_CXX_FLAGS})
    SET(MY_CXX_FLAGS ${MY_CXX_FLAGS} ${MY_C_AND_CXX_FLAGS})

    IF(MINGW)
        SET(MY_C_FLAGS   ${MY_C_FLAGS}   -static-libgcc)
        SET(MY_CXX_FLAGS ${MY_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)
    ENDIF(MINGW)

    IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
        SET(MY_C_FLAGS   ${MY_C_FLAGS}   -g2 -Wall)
        SET(MY_CXX_FLAGS ${MY_CXX_FLAGS} -g2 -Wall)
    ELSE()
        SET(MY_C_FLAGS   ${MY_C_FLAGS}   -O2 -Wno-error)
        SET(MY_CXX_FLAGS ${MY_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -Wno-error)
    ENDIF()

    FOREACH(C_COMPILE_FLAG ${MY_C_FLAGS})
        ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${C_COMPILE_FLAG}>)
    ENDFOREACH()

    FOREACH(CXX_COMPILE_FLAG ${MY_CXX_FLAGS})
        ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${CXX_COMPILE_FLAG}>)
    ENDFOREACH()

    # for the gcc -fstack-protector* flags we need libssp
    # clang does not have this
    IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE} -lssp")
        SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE   "${CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE}   -lssp")
    ENDIF()
ENDIF()

# Assembler flags

IF(ASM_ENABLED)
    FOREACH(ASM_FLAG -I${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/filters/hq/asm/ -O1 -w-orphan-labels)
        ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM_NASM>:${ASM_FLAG}>)
    ENDFOREACH()
ENDIF(ASM_ENABLED)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of requiring a particular standard to the compiler, cmake 3.1 solves the issue by providing a way to request a standard version or a set of compiler features. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165519/1900563) and to the [official documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

checkout the [ucm_add_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_add_flags) and [ucm_print_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_print_flags) macros of [ucm](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm) - to add compiler flags to the appropriate cmake variables and to inspect the results

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with `-lstdc++fs`.

In the end, the thing that solve it to me was `target_link_libraries`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main -lstdc++fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a better method that works on older versions of cmake, e.g. Ubuntu 14 has 2.8.12, and target expressions are 3.3 feature.

Here is how you would set some C++ specific flags:

```
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "<FLAGS>" "<FLAGS> -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fexceptions " CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I currently use:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-std=c++0x)
    add_definitions(-std=gnu++11)
endif()
```

Or, if you have an older version of cmake and you want to see it show up in cmake-gui:

```
set_property(CACHE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS PROPERTY VALUE "-std=c++0x")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this situation with C++ / clr project, where I needed to modify two variables - `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` can be modified using `set_source_files_properties / COMPILE_FLAGS`, but not `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.
I've concluded to create separate, project specific cmake file, in separate folder.
If project is isolated - then variable modifying will work only within current C++/clr project.

I guess if you want to have multiple C++ projects and multiple C++/clr projects, makes sense to separate them at least in two different folder (if not more) - native C++ specific, and managed C++ specific.

In similar manner you can find out on cmake test application:
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/CSharpLinkToCxx/CMakeLists.txt

Here is the same thing, only with more explanation:

```
# These variables affects also other C++ projects, that's why separate cmake for this c++ dll

# Clr compiling requires these:

# "Enable C++ Exceptions" - "Yes (/EHsc)" => "Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa)"
string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "/EHa" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

# "Basic Run-time checks" - "Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu) (/RTC1)" => "Default"
string(REPLACE "/RTC1" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

This is one approach. If you however want to generate native c++ and managed c++ projects in a loop - one approach is to disable global flags:

```
# Disable global flag, configure on per project basis, using target_compile_options, target_link_options
string(REPLACE "/RTC1" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
string(REPLACE "/INCREMENTAL" "" CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
#string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

and then configure each project setting individually for each project, for example like this:

```
if(${is_managed})
    # Managed C++ code
    set_target_properties(${project} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_CLRSupport "true")
    set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.7.2")

    # Being able to debug dll
    target_link_options(${project} PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/ASSEMBLYDEBUG>")

    # Disable incremental linking
    target_link_options(${project} PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/INCREMENTAL:NO>")

    # "Enable C++ Exceptions" - "Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa)"
    set(compile_flags /EHa)
else()
    # Native C++ code
    # "Basic Run-time checks" - "Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu) (/RTC1)" => "Default"
    target_compile_options(${project} PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/RTC1>")

    # Enable incremental linking
    target_link_options(${project} PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/INCREMENTAL>")

    # "Enable C++ Exceptions" - "Yes (/EHsc)"
    set(compile_flags /EHsc)
endif()
set_target_properties(${project} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${compile_flags})
```