# For Cmake, can you modify the release/debug compiler flags with `add_compiler_flags()` command?

Tags: c++, cmake

In the man page for `add_compile_options()` I don't see any mention of how to modify the Release/Debug compiler flags. **Can you use `add_compiler_options()` to modify the Release/Debug compiler flags? If yes, how?**

**If no, is the recommended canonical method to modify [the release/debug cmake variables[1] as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake) ?**

[1]
i.e. set the cmake variables CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<TYPE> (for lang c/c++ it would be: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG, CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE, CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to reuse your compiler settings through several of your projects or you need to differentiate the compiler options between C and C++, I would recommend the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`/`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variant with a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) for each of your supported compilers (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory)).

But if you just need some additional C++ compiler options in your project, taking [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_compile_options.html), [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_compile_options.html) or [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_compile_features.html) is the way to go.

And yes, you can differentiate between `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` there.

**Examples**

1. The `add_compile_options()` command does take [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions%287%29):

   ```
   add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/MDd>")
   ```

   or

   ```
   add_compile_options(
       "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-std=gnu99>"
       "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-std=gnu99 -g3>"
   )
   ```
2. Better to check also the compiler id:

   ```
   add_compile_options("$<$<AND:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/MDd>")
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (MSVC)
       add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/MDd>")
   endif()
   ```
3. Even better to let CMake decide [the correct compiler options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features%287%29) for you. So you can either set the [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD) needed for your target:

   > ```
   > set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
   > ```

   or give the [compiler feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#prop_gbl:CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES) your target needs with [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_compile_features.html)

   > ```
   > add_library(mylib requires_constexpr.cpp)
   >  # cxx_constexpr is a usage-requirement
   >  target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_constexpr)
   > ```

**References**

- [CMake CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS enabled optimization unexpectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115549/cmake-cmake-cxx-flags-enabled-optimization-unexpectly)
- [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)
- [CMake generator expression, differentiate C / C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525047/cmake-generator-expression-differentiate-c-c-code)

Comment: Just to make sure - is this still the recommended way in 2020 / cmake 3.17?

Comment: @Jay No, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake