cmake: propage compile definitions to library
I'm building ARM Cortex-M project with GCC and I have several small libraries, which are defined in cmake as follows below, but each in its own CMakeLists.txt file:
# Lib 1
add_library(libname1)
target_sources(libname1 PRIVATE libname1.c)
target_include_directories(libname1 PUBLIC path/to/include/dir)

# Lib 2
add_library(libname1)
target_sources(libname2 PRIVATE libname1.c)
target_include_directories(libname1 PUBLIC path/to/include/dir)

I'm linking them to the executable as:
# Core specific compilation flags
set(cpu_flags -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16)

add_executable(project_name)
target_sources(project_name PRIVATE source.c)
target_include_directories(project_name ....)
target_compile_options(project_name PUBLIC ${cpu_flags})
target_link_libraries(project_name libname1)
target_link_libraries(project_name libname2)

The problem with this is that cpu_flags are not propagated to the libraries. The only way so far is to manually add the cpu flags to each library, like so:

add_executable(project_name)
target_sources(project_name PRIVATE source.c)
target_include_directories(project_name ....)
target_compile_options(project_name PUBLIC ${cpu_flags})

# Add flags to lib manually, then link
target_compile_options(libname1 PUBLIC ${cpu_flags})
target_link_libraries(project_name libname1)
target_compile_options(libname2 PUBLIC ${cpu_flags})
target_link_libraries(project_name libname2)

Since I have many libraries like so, is there a way to globally define compiler specific flags that will apply to all libs, and same for symbols and/or include paths?

Commands add_compile_options, add_compile_definitions are all about global compiler flags. Make sure to call such command in the top-level CMakeLists.txt, before including directories with libraries and executables.

@Tsyvarev What I've noticed is that add_compile_options does not accept expressions, even if this is written in the docs. add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-Wno-deprecated>) produces this in the compile_commands.json file: \"$$<0:\" -Wno-deprecated > \" and then build fails (GCC cannot parse flags..)

Solved from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525047/cmake-generator-expression-differentiate-c-c-code
